# R-markdown self_contained

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using R-markdown for a couple of reports. I do it with self contained graphics because I send it via email.

This worked till recently. But now the images are not shown anymore (with the error of a cross in a box). It might be that I updated the Version of RStudio. I used this a the top of the script:

```
---
title: "blablablab"
author: "blablablab"
output:
html_document:
fig_caption: yes
toc: no
toc_depth: 2
toc_float: no
number_sections: false
self_contained: yes
---
```

I know that this question is not very specific. I just wanted to ask if there is anybody which also had self contained graphics which suddenly didn't work anymore.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Greetings Dani

Comment: Can you please expand your example to include a graphic that is not working for you (e.g. from the default Rmarkdown document created in RStudio) and correct the indentation levels in the YAML headers. This way we get a [mcve] and the question will become quite specific.

Answer (score 5):

I just had same problem.  In RStudio i had previously:

```
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: yes
```

and it always worked properly producing self-contained HTML.  TODAY it stopped working properly.  I did update Rstudio a few weeks ago and might not have noticed problem, not sure.   SO now i changed to:

```
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: yes
    mode: selfcontained
```

Which seems strange and redundant with two separate lines trying to make things self-contained BUT it worked.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago.  I would like to be able to post the html on MS teams and get the DT:datatable output to show.  I was hoping selfcontained would do it.

Answer (score 0):

As a sanity check, make sure that you do **not** have the option `include=FALSE` in your global chunk options `opts_chunk$set`

When that is the case, the images are created and stored in the `figure-html` directory, but not embedded in the html file.