# Html document from RMarkdown unformats when send to others

Tags: html, r, email, r-markdown

I have a markdown document in HTML that works just fine in my computer after rendering.
However, I would like to send it to other people, but when I send it via e-mail, in the computer of the person who received the document, some of the graphs and maps on the document disappear and the "toc" also disappears, not giving the option of hiding or showing the code.
I rendered the document in a macbook pc. Is that the problem? How do I fix it?
Thank you

I send it to myself via e-mail and the same thing happened when opening the html on my iphone.

Comment: I think there is a possible option to `html output` in the YAML header, that says: `self contained: yes`. Because if you do not have it, I suspect your graphs will be stored in a folder alongside the html document. If you do not send that folder with the document, the images will be gone. Setting it the output to self contained will hopefully help. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927599/r-markdown-self-contained and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316205/how-can-i-create-a-self-contained-html-report-with-rmarkdown